# Can I use my laptop to mine bitcoins?

Tags: cpu-mining

I was just wondering if it is possible to mine BTC using my laptop.

If so, what sort of graphics card should I get for this computer and 
what could I expect to mine in bitcoins a day with a single graphics card.

I would really appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 3):

The times when one could mine Bitcoins with a laptop or graphics card are long gone. You would never even cover the cost of the electricity used. Bitcoin mining is done with ASICs now.

Comment: Thanks for answering, could you please tell if 100 ghz/s ASIC is competitive enough today?

Comment: A 100GH/s ASIC will produce about 0.0426 BTC per day right now, which is worth about $1,000 per month. Of course, that rate is dropping. Whether that's competitive depends on how much it will cost, when you'll get it, how much power it needs, and what you pay for power.

Answer (score 0):

At this difficulty, you may take 1 year to get 0.01 BTC. So, stop using computers to mining. Check some real bitcoin miners mining, like Avalon, KNC…, Avalon from best-miner.com is good, KNC is great too but they are pre-orders.